# Split Cell Value Into two VBA variables

Tags: excel, vba

In a scenario, I'm wanting to take the value of a certain cell (raw material) (a number) and split it between two finished products on a production flow sheet.

I need to know what VBA I could execute if for example cell B1 on 'STOCK' sheet was 8. It would then go to 'PLAN' sheet and find the next available row on column A and paste 'RAW', then go to column T, find the next available row and paste 'RAW', then back to column A and so on until I had four 'RAW' cells under each column.

Could anyone give me a hand? Thanks!

Edit.

So here is the current VBA for adding the 'Current stock'. It's not fully complete as it's just a concept.
[image: code]

It takes this 'raw data'

[image: raw data]

And puts it in the next blank row for each column.

[image: populated]

Now I want to do this in a similar fashion, but instead of using the value, I want it to find the next blank row between TWO COLUMNS. so B&T, C&U etc etc because the raw product makes two types of finished products

[image: finish]

Comment: I think you need to post an example of the current sheet, and what you would be looking to get back. Also, how far have you got with the code so far? Post that up too.

Comment: @DavyC Here is a link to the workbook https://www.mediafire.com/?vceo3wtac39pxfq

Basically, running Macro1 will take the raw data from 'FINISH' and however many of that particular product is finished it will add a value to the next available row of that particular item's column.

Now I want it to do exactly the same with the 'RAW' products, but split it between the two, so B&T, C&U, D&V etc etc, because one RAW product can make two types of finish product.

It's a VERY VAGUE concept and difficult to explain at the moment..

Comment: There are not many people that will download and open a .xlsm worksheet from the web.  It is too dangerous.  Please post the relevant code directly into the original post.

Comment: @ScottCraner Have edited original question and explain a little more to try and make sense of the confusing question